# Is $f$ Riemann integrable?

Tags: riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Suppose that there exists a sequence $(P_{n})_{n}$ of partitions of $[a,b]$ so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} L(f,P_{n})=L= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} U(f,P_{n})$, where $L$ denotes the lower sum and $U$ the upper sum.

Does it follow that $f$ is Riemann integrable? (If it is, then I'm certain the value of the integral is equal to $L$.)

Comment: What if each term of the sequence is constant? You may need the sequence monotone so that for any partition $P$ you can find a partition $P_{n_0}$ finer than $P$.

Comment: I was thinking: "Isn't that the definition of the Riemann integral?" But I see on Wikipedia that it's the Darboux integral that uses upper and lower sums. However, the Darboux integral (or if we should say "the Darboux definition") is equivalent to the Riemann integral. Therefore the answer to your question should be 'yes'.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral

Comment: I understood that the main difference to the definition is rather that we ae given a "there exists (a sequence of partitions and need to show a "for all"

Comment: How much do you know about integrability? What about the theorems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By assumption we know that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exist partitions $Q$ and $Q'$ of $[a,b]$ for which $$L(f,Q)>L-\frac12\varepsilon $$ and $$U(f,Q')<L+\frac 12\varepsilon$$ If $P$ is a common refinement of $Q$ and $Q'$, one has $$L(f,P) \ge L(f,Q)>L-\frac12\varepsilon $$ and $$U(f,P) \le U(f,Q')<L+\frac 12\varepsilon$$ Subtracting last inequalities, we obtain $$U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \varepsilon $$ It follows that $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ by a well known criterion.

Since $$L(f,P_n)\le \int_a^b f \le U(f,P_n)$$ the statement is proved.

Comment: Thanks you for your insights!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Given $\epsilon>0$, we have to show that there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every partition $P$ finer than $\delta$, we have $L-\epsilon < L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)<L+\epsilon$.

Let $M$ be a bounf for $f$, $|f(x)|<M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.
From what is given, we know that there exists $N$ such that $L-\frac\epsilon2<L(f,P_N)\le U(f,P_N)<L+\frac\epsilon2$.
Let $x_0=a<x_1<\ldots < x_m=b$ be the points making up partition $P_N$.
For some $\delta>0$, consider a partition $P$ that is finer than $\delta$.
If $f_{P_n}$ and $f_P$ are the respective staircase functions used to compute the lower sum with respect to $P_N$ and $P$, then we have $f_P(x)\ge f_{P_N}(x)$ for all $x$ except possibly those in the up to $m+1$ intervals of $P$ that contain a point of $P_N$.
For these intervals we of course have the trival estimate $f_P(x)\ge -M$ and $f_{P_N}(x)\le M$.
Therefore 
$$L(f,P)+2M(m+1)\delta \ge L(f,P_N).$$
Hence it suffices to make $\delta<\frac\epsilon{4M(m+1)}$ in order to ensure $$L(f,P)\ge L(f,P_N)-\frac\epsilon2>L-\epsilon.$$
A similar argument shows that then also 
$$U(f,P)\le U(f,P_N)+\frac\epsilon2<L+\epsilon.$$

Comment: Why can't we just observe that if $P'$ is $any$ refinement of $P_N$ then $\epsilon-L/2\le L(P_N)\le L(P')\le U(P')\le U(P_N)\le\epsilon +L/2?$ so that we may take $\delta<|P_N|?$|

Comment: Why does this proof look overly complicated? Unless you are trying to avoid using that Riemann integral and Darboux integral are equivalent, this proof is too long to follow.